# Renaming file on upload

Tags: php, file, upload, rename

I'm trying to upload an image to the server using a PHP script. It works fine, till I want to change the filename using a variable in the name.

I want to rename the file to the logged in users username_filename.extension, but it just skips the username variable so the name becomes: `_filename.extension`.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./global.php";

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    $username = $row['username'];

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $ext = explode('.',$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);
    $extension = $ext[1];
    $newname =  '/var/www/picturebox/albums/' . $username . '_' . $ext[0] . '.' . $ext[1];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$newname);
}
?>
```

And the filename becomes `_filename.extension`

Anyone knows what to do?

Just found out that it works fine in IE, but now in Chrome. Any suggestions on a solution?

Comment: The most possible issue is that $username variable is empty. Can you var_dump it?

Comment: Better yet, `var_dump( $row )`.

Comment: Better yet, post more code. We don't know if your two code snippets are in the same function or even in the same file. You might have variable scope issues among all the other possible causes.

Comment: Always suspect the emptiness of vars in times like this. Are you sure you're running `session_start()` and that the DB row is actually returning anything?

Comment: I changed the question. Now, you see the whole php file that contains the upload script. If I echo the $username, it returns my username so it isn't empty :S

Comment: So if you `echo $username` you get `"foo"` but if you do `echo $newname` you get just `/var/www/picturebox/albums/_filename.extension`?

Comment: Yes Juhana. That is exactly what happens, and I can't find out why.

Comment: what does var_dump($row) output?

Comment: array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(13) "daniellundahl" ["password"]=> string(32) "***" ["email"]=> string(26) "***" ["admin"]=> string(1) "***" }

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$username` with `$row['username']` in your `$newname` string?

Comment: so, if you do a `var_dump($row);` right before your `$newname =` line, does it still output as expected?

Comment: Yes sk00v, it does. I tried to remove the if(!empty($_FILES)) wrapper, and it still gives the same result.

Comment: It works in IE.. I always use Chrome and it doesn't work there. Someone that knows why? :S